# wp_nav_menu with default pages menu

Tags: theme-development

i'm using wp_nav_menu to generate a navigation menu for my theme. It works fine by selecting my created menus. But, what if i want to generate a list from my already created pages and subpages in wordpress ? I tried using wp_page_menu, which does what i want, but i cannot pass a css class parameter to the inside ul, in order to stylize my menu.

Does anyone know how i can do that ?

Comment: Are there sub-sub-pages (i.e. up to what depth does it need to work?)? Do several pages have children or is there but one with sub-pages? If there are more than one, is it satisfactory if all inside `<ul>` elements have the same class?

Comment: It's just enough if only the outer ul has a class specification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced that problem in the past, however I remember my problem was the first link didn't have a class, after some research I solved it working with a structure similar to this one, take a look and let me know if it works :)

```
<ul>
   <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

UPDATED....

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply :) It actually does not work and the reason is that wp_list_pages already creates an inner <ul> that messes with the external <ul> that you specify. What i would want to do is set the class name for the internal <ul> produced by wp_list_pages.

Comment: @SpyrosP While Andrew's "first link" issue has nothing in common with your problem whatsoever, [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) is a solution to it. When called with an empty `title_li=` parameter (as he does above), the list the function does generate will not be wrapped in `<ul></ul>`. Hence you can define classes for the outer `<ul>` using regular markup.

Comment: Actually that is what I was meaning, my problem was not exactly the same, however the title_li= empty basically do not wrap the into the <ul> </ul>, I just copy and paste the code I used. My bad for do not explain myself better.  @SpyrosP did you check the output it generates?

Comment: Yeap, thanx for the clarification, that's exactly what i wanted :)